# Using Python loops and Venn Diagram to decide which language to learn to speak

Tags: python, dataset, data-visualization, multilingual, venn-diagram

I want to learn to speak a new language; however, I cannot decide which language would be most beneficial. I am new to data science and Python and I tried to write a script to help me decide which language would be best. 
I wanted to be able to communicate with the most amount of people from the most number of countries. I know that Mandarin can let me speak with the most people because of the number of native speakers, but they are all from the same country (or nearly).
I used data from https://worldpopulationreview.com/countries/
I was able to download a CSV, but I was not completely sure how to use a CSV, especially using Google CoLabs.

So, I created a loop to generate a list of where both French and English are not primary languages. I would like to add more languages to this eventually, but I wanted to start small. 
I then created a second script, I guess that is what you would call it, and used both of the source lists. But when I created the Venn Diagram it only shows a number not the languages in the list.

I hope that makes sense, I would appreciate any help. Here is what I have created so far.

```
english_language = ["Antigua", "Barbuda","Australia","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belize","Botswana","Brunei","Burundi","Cameroon","Canada","Cook Islands","Cyprus","Dominica","Eritrea","Ethiopia","Fiji","Ghana","Grenada","Guyana","India","Ireland","Israel","Jamaica","Jordan","Kenya","Kiribati","Kuwait","Lesotho","Liberia","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Malta","Marshall Islands","Mauritius","Myanmar","Namibia","Nauru","Nepal","New Zealand","Nigeria","Niue","Pakistan","Palau","Papua New Guinea","Philippines","Qatar","Rwanda","Saint Kitts and Nevis","Saint Lucia","Saint Vincent and the Grenadines","Samoa","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Solomon Islands","South Africa","South Sudan","Sri Lanka","Sudan","Tanzania","Tonga","Trinidad and Tobago","Tuvalu","Uganda","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","United States","Vanuatu","Zambia","Zimbabwe"]
french_language = ["Belgium", "Benin", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Centeral African Republic", "Chad", "Comoros", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "DR Congo", "Equatorial Guinea", "France", "Gabon", "Guinea", "Haiti", "Ivory Coast", "Luxembourg", "Madagascar", "Mali", "Monaco", "Niger", "Republic of the Congo", "Rwanda", "Saint Lucia", "Senegal", "Seychelles", "Switzerland", "Togo", "Vanuatu"]
french_primary= []
english_primary = []
both_spoken = []
single = []

for countries in french_language:
  if countries not in english_language:
    single.append(countries)
  else:
    both_spoken.append(countries)
for second_countries in english_language:
  if second_countries not in french_language:
    english_primary.append(second_countries)    
print("Both languages spoken", both_spoken)
print("French is a primary language", single)  
print("English is primary", english_primary)
```

I then created a ven diagram in another block

```
#import matplotlib as mpl
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib_venn import venn2, venn2_circles

venn2([set(english_language), set(french_language)])
```

Could anyone please let me know if I am even on the right track? I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I created a kernel https://www.kaggle.com/bcantt/select-language?scriptVersionId=30070686 hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much, that went way over my head. I will need to study more for sure. Thank you so much. I was way off.

Comment: I am still trying to figure it out, I was hoping you could help me understand
del language_dic['']

why are you deleting language_dic?  And what is the "" for? Is to delete the blank dictionary?

Comment: there was a none value distrupting my calculations, I deleted it.